# Wrapper div height is 0 with floated elements inside

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a wrapper `<div>` which contains two inner `<div>`s that are floating.

```
<div class="outside" style="border:1px solid #555;">
  <div class="inside" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="inside2" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

The problem is the wrapper `<div>` has width of 80px since two inner `<div>` are 40px each. But always the wrapper `<div>` is `0px` in height which makes the border appear like a line at the top.

So I placed the two inner `<div>`s inside a `<table>`. It worked well. But how do I avoid this problem without going for a `<table>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which method of ‘clearfix’ is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent.

```
<div class="outside" style="border:1px solid #555;overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="inside" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="inside2" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why does it collapse like that in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

The outer `div` is [collapsing](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) because the two child `div`s inside of it are floating. The easiest fix for this is to set `overflow: hidden;` on the outer `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="outside" style="border:1px solid #555; overflow:auto">
<div class="inside" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
<div class="inside2" style="float:left; width:40px;">CONTENT</div>
</div>//Outside container close
```